# Como utilizar meu banco de dados Firebird já populado pra um projeto Web no visual Studio 2015 usando entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework, firebird, conexão, visual-studio-2015, banco-de-dados

Tenho um banco de dados Firebird já populado e gostaria de utilizar esta mesma base para um projeto Web no visual studio 2015.

Já instalei Firebird ADO.NET Data Provider e tentei dar um "conect to database" no visual studio, selecionei "Firebird Data Source", dei continue mas quando seleciono o DB na janela "add conecction" a janela fecha e tenho que recomeçar o processo em "conect to database".

Como posso fazer esta conexão do meu DB Firebird com o VS ?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Esta é a maneira antiga de trabalhar com o Entity Framework. A maneira mais atual usa apenas configurações do arquivo de projeto `web.config` e pacotes NuGet.

O provedor ADO.NET ao Firebird e seu respectivo suporte ao Entity Framework podem ser facilmente instalados utilizando os seguintes comandos no Package Manager Console (<kbd>View</kbd> > <kbd>Other Windows</kbd> > <kbd>Package Manager Console</kbd>):

```
PM> Install-Package FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient
PM> Install-Package EntityFramework.Firebird
```

A configuração no `web.config` é feita da seguinte forma:

```
  <configuration>
    ...
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="FirebirdSql.Data.EntityFramework6.FbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework.Firebird" />
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" type="FirebirdSql.Data.EntityFramework6.FbProviderServices, EntityFramework.Firebird" />
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
    ...
  </configuration>
```

Além disso, é preciso informar uma *connection string* no mesmo arquivo:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="User=usuario;Password=senha;Database=C:/caminho/do/arquivo.fdb;DataSource=localhost;Port=3050;Dialect=3;Charset=NONE;Role=;Connection lifetime=15;Pooling=true;MinPoolSize=0;MaxPoolSize=50;Packet size=8192;ServerType=0;" providerName="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  ...
</configuration>
```

---

**EDIT**

Para engenharia reversa, instale o provider DDEX no seu Visual Studio. [Você pode baixá-lo aqui](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/additional-downloads/).

Comment: Instalei os pacotes já mas pretendia utilizar uma class library para o modelo. Como faço esta configuração no class library ?

Comment: Faça outra pergunta, por favor. Vai ficar meio fora de contexto eu colocar tudo aqui.

Comment: Utilizo o App.config?     
Gostaria de fazer do outro jeito para gerar as classes de domínio através do DB usando engenharia reversa no Entity Framework. É possível fazer isso ? Obrigado.

Comment: @VictorGlauber Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendes Já estou com o DDEX instalado, o VS reconhece o _Firebird Data Source (.NET Framework Data Provider for Firebird)_  como possibilidade para Adicionar uma nova conexão VS - DB mas o VS ou cancela a operação de add conection e volta na tela inicial ou trava e reinicia. Tem alguma outra forma de fazer a Engenharia reversa neste caso? Obrigado

Comment: Estou instalando os providers aqui pra reproduzir o problema. Aparentemente é algo na sua configuração.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34882/discussion-between-victor-glauber-and-cigano-morrison-mendez).

Answer (score 0):

Consegui fazer a conexão apenas da maneira mais antiga, criando uma Connection String e acessando o DB por chamadas SQL. 
Isto vai dificultar bastante pra mim desenvolvendo, pois não vou conseguir utilizar code first do modo que gostaria.

Caso mais alguém necessite de ajuda neste mesmo problema segue o link que me auxiliou. [AQUI!](http://www.devmedia.com.br/conectando-em-uma-base-de-dados-firebird-com-c/11938)