# Como fazer Engenharia reversa via EntityFramework utilizando uma fonte de dados Firebird no VisualStudio 2015?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, firebird, visual-studio-2015

Tenho um banco de dados Firebird já populado e gostaria de utilizar esta mesma base para um projeto Web no visual studio 2015.

Gostaria de utilizar uma class library e gerar o modelo usando EF Code-First – Partindo de uma base existente mas num servidor Firebird .

Já instalei Firebird ADO.NET Data Provider e tentei dar um "conect to database" no visual studio, selecionei "Firebird Data Source", dei continue mas quando seleciono o DB na janela "add conecction" a janela fecha e tenho que recomeçar o processo em "conect to database" ou o VS trava e reinicia.

Não resolveu, então instalei o ADO.NET firebird, conforme abaixo:

```
PM> Install-Package FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient
PM> Install-Package EntityFramework.Firebird
```

Mas ainda não consigo conectar o DB com o VisualStudio.

Alguém sabe como resolvo?

Obrigado.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como utilizar meu banco de dados Firebird já populado pra um projeto Web no visual Studio 2015 usando entity framework?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/110135/como-utilizar-meu-banco-de-dados-firebird-j%c3%a1-populado-pra-um-projeto-web-no-visu)

Comment: @Randrade Não é duplicata. Eu pedi pra ele abrir. Agora o que ele precisa é usar a IDE para realizar engenharia reversa do banco.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Eu pensei que fosse algo do tipo, mas não achei nenhum aviso na pergunta anterior.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, depedendo da versão do VS do AP, ele pode precisar instalar o [`EF Tools`](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762) para pode gerar o modelo Code-First apartir de um banco de dados existente.

Comment: @TobyMosque sabe se é normal o Visual Studio travar e fechar quando tento importar a base de dados?

Comment: @VictorGlauber, nenhum fechamento forçado após erro é normal.

Comment: @TobyMosque estou travado com este problema desde ontem, não encontro solução alguma.

Comment: @TobyMosque Vou colocar isso na resposta. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Instale o Firebird ADO.NET Data Provider e o DDEX, [disponíveis aqui](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/additional-downloads/), com o Visual Studio **fechado**.

Experimente repetir o procedimento de engenharia reversa logo após.

---

**EDIT**

[Conforme a dica do @TobyMosque](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/110206/como-fazer-engenharia-reversa-via-entityframework-utilizando-uma-fonte-de-dados?noredirect=1#comment228785_110206), pode ser necessário instalar as [EF Tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762).

Comment: Já está instalado o DDEX e o Provider mas quando tento selecionar o DB para fazer o procedimento de engenharia reversa o VS trava ou fecha a janela. Parece ser algum bug da IDE, estou tentando reparar a instalação do VS para tentar fazer o procedimento novamente e testar. Logo trago um retorno.

Comment: @VictorGlauber Eu atualizei a resposta. Tente as EF Tools também.